# Menu effects slide

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to make slide effect on click for all in magento.For example if I click on mobile menu it should show as Slide down and it should hide as Slide up.

Comment: I tried with slide up and slide down in app.js where add class and remove class were there and it doesn't work properly

Answer (score 0):

Using prototype which should work with magento 1.9 use the following

```
Effect.SlideUp('id_of_element');
Effect.SlideDown('id_of_element');
```

If you know how to setup Jquery then use the following:

```
$('class_or_id_of_element').slideUp();  //don't forget the . or #
$('class_or_id_of_element').slideDown();  //don't forget the . or #
```